# Can $\sqrt{a}^\sqrt{b}$ be rational if $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$ are irrational?

Tags: number-theory, exponentiation, radicals, rationality-testing

> Let $a$ and $b$ be rational numbers, such that $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$ are irrational.
>
> Can $\sqrt{a}^\sqrt{b}$ be rational?

I found examples, where the irrational power of an irrational number is rational, but in those examples at least one of those numbers (base and exponent) has not been a square root of a rational.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since ${\sqrt{a}}^{\sqrt{b}}$ is expressed as an algebraic number not equal to $0$ or $1$ raised to an irrational algebraic power, the result will be transcendental (and hence irrational) by the [Gelfond–Schneider theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem).